# How to copy and paste by using Keyboard in python?

Tags: python, copy-paste

Also, are there any functions I can use keyboard to control in order to create a program more efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: How to copy and paste info by using keyboard in Python

Comment: Are you saying that ctrl-c in the interactive mode should be doing anything differently than what it does? Your question is extremely difficult to understand.

Comment: @hkus10: Try to explain what your problem is, instead of asking us how to do something that you think you need to do, but you don't. Include the following information: 1. What are you trying to do. 2 Why are you trying to do it. 3. What do you expect to happen. 4. What happens.

Comment: @Tom Willis: Please normalize. /facepalm*10^6 :)

Comment: No this post makes a lot of sense interactive interpreter does not behaves the same way as Windows DOS behaves all newbies who type 2-3 lines of code blocks on terminal when face errors would like to type the same programm again on terminal and retype to save it we need to do a Ctrl+V but Ctrl+V pastes the white spaces and three dots ... which are after each line break and hence the program execution gives a lot of error this is what OP I think is trying to ask

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to copy/paste source code/text in the Python command line?

If you're on Windows, it works just like any DOS console. I recommend you open your Python console, click on the left upper icon and select "Properties". Then, on the options tab, check the "Insert mode" and "Quick Edit mode" checkboxes.

Now you can copy text by highlighting it with your mouse and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and paste text by right-clicking inside the window.

Comment: +1 for understanding this question...

Comment: How can I do this in Mac? Facing the same problem.